# convert .CSV file to JSON file in php on button click (WP plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress

**Base Functionality:** How could I use PHP to take my .csv file, and convert it to a JSON file; on button click.

```
function Converter(){ 
    $fh = fopen("files/locationsCSV.csv", "r");

    $csvData = array();

    while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $csvData[] = $row;
    }
    // echo json_encode($csvData);
    // Here I would like to output json file 'files/locationsCSV.json'
}
```

**More context;** I am trying to do this as a Wordpress plugin: Below is my full code below, currently it's just outputting a white screen of death. I would like a button to appear in in my defined 'page' in Wordpress below. Once the button is clicked, it converts the file from .csv to .json.

---

```
<?php

function Plugin_Template () {

    /** Step 2 (from text above). */
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

    /** Step 1. */
    function my_plugin_menu() {
        add_options_page( 'El Plan Plugin Options', 'El Plan Finder v2', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
    }

    /** Step 3. */
    function my_plugin_options() {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
            wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<button class="convert">Convert.</button>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    function Converter(){ 
        $fh = fopen("files/locationsCSV.csv", "r");

        $csvData = array();

        while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $csvData[] = $row;
        }
        // echo json_encode($csvData);
        file_put_contents("files/locationsCSV.json",json_encode($csvData))      
    }
}

Plugin_Template();
```

Comment: `file_put_contents("filename.json",json_encode($csvData))`?

Comment: I would suggest you use line-delimited JSON instead.  If your entire dataset is one large JSON object, the whole thing has to be parsed and put into memory at once.  If you have multiple records, then you can separate them in your file by newline characters, and then only one record needs to be parsed at a time.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply try

```
$fp = fopen('files/locationsCSV.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($csvData));
fclose($fp);
```

OR

```
$file  = "files/locationsCSV.csv";
$csv   = file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
$fp    = fopen('files/locationsCSV.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($array));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: No, i want to convert a .csv to JSON. I do not already have a JSON

Comment: @CaptainRon try to put get_template_directory() before the files/locationsCSV.json

Comment: Thanks; the problem with this- I would have to create a blank json file to be populated? I want this to generate